# Why "chickentown" in Clarke's "Evidently Chickentown"

Tags: poetry, meaning

[Evidently Chickentown](http://www.cyberspike.com/clarke/chicktow.html) (warning NSFW language) by John Cooper Clarke. I gather the overall meaning of the poem is, to quote after [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidently_Chickentown), to *convey a sense of futility and exasperation [through the use of repeated profanity]*.

What I don't understand is why the author chose to go with *Chickentown* since chicken is, as far as I know, a metaphor for a coward. **Is the titular Chickentown a reference or is there some other meaning behind it (or none)?**

Comment: **Personal Opinion Alert**: It's just a name, chosen largely for its rhythm and sound. JCC has always been a performer; I imagine he liked it as much for the invective he could put into speaking it as for any particular meaning, hidden or otherwise. Yes, it's meant to be a bit derogatory as well, but only in general terms I'd say. Who knows though - he's a poet.

Comment: Fucking stolen, fucking bloody/Fucking straight from fucking Orkney.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about artistic choices made by a performer, not the English language per se.

Answer (score 1):

JHCL is largely correct, I believe, in suggesting that the poet John Cooper Clarke chose the words *'Chicken Town'* because of the rhythm and sound.  The *'ck'* in *'Chicken'* echoes the profanity used repeatedly in the poem.

John Cooper Clarke has acknowledged that the poem 'Bloody Orkney' was probably an unconscious influence on him.  A link to that poem, written during World War II, is posted here: http://tomclarkblog.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/hamish-blair-bloody-orkney.html.

It is perhaps salient that the originally created and spoken version of 'Bloody Orkney' was almost certainly 'F..king Orkney', and again the *'f'* and the *'k'* are repeated between the profanity and the subjects of the profanity (as in -kerbs -flicks -folks, etc).

John Cooper Clarke's biography gives no particular clues to where he might have lived, or a place he might have known, which was perhaps known to the locals as 'Chicken Town'.  There may have been a slightly more abstract origin.  Cooper Clark has expressed a view in interviews that he is against commercialism and commodification.

In an interview with Tim Adams of the Guardian Newspaper (UK) in 2014 (http://www.theguardian.com/books/2014/apr/06/john-cooper-clarke-poetry-bard-salford) he said:

> I was in a high street the other day – it was three chicken outlets, two bookies, a Poundland and a Costcutter. A place where you pawn your possessions, a place where you stock up on shite food and a place where you lose your cash on a bet to get you out of there.

One might imagine that he is no fan of fast food chicken outlets, or towns or cultures that are built around them, and there may be some reflection of that contempt in his choice of title of this poem.

Conversely, he may have had in mind some reference to Southern Fried Chicken, a staple of the Southern States of the United States, and by association small towns in such places. I make no judgement, but it may be that Cooper Clark had these sort of towns in mind when he wrote this poem - or as others have observed, adapted the existing poem, 'Bloody Orkney' to a modern setting.  For a discussion on Southern Fried Chicken, see: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/15364/where-did-southern-fried-chicken-come-from.